# Error in R function. Attempt to select less than one element in intergerOneIndex

Tags: r, for-loop

I created some random trial data as follows:

```
Trial1 <- AminoAcidTrialGenerator2(10, 6, aacodons$MOD_Frequency); Trial1
```

This is created with a function that I wrote to generate sequences of amino acids in 3letter code based on a probability distribution.

This outputs:

```
[[1]]
[1] cys  glu  glu  stop phe  asn 
21 Levels: ala arg asn asp cys gln glu gly his ile leu lys ... val

[[2]]
[1] cys pro ile lys cys arg
21 Levels: ala arg asn asp cys gln glu gly his ile leu lys ... val

[[3]]
[1] asp gln gln ala gln his
21 Levels: ala arg asn asp cys gln glu gly his ile leu lys ... val

[[4]]
[1] thr pro lys thr lys phe
21 Levels: ala arg asn asp cys gln glu gly his ile leu lys ... val

[[5]]
[1] ala  gly  his  arg  stop trp 
21 Levels: ala arg asn asp cys gln glu gly his ile leu lys ... val
```

What my emperical.codon.freq function is supposed to do is to create a new list TrialData that contains the counts of frequency that each three letter character occurs in each trial.

```
emperical.Codon.Freq <- function(trialvec) {
  TrialData <- list()
  ecf.df <- data.frame(Codon = aacodons$Amino_Acid)
  for (i in 1:length(unlist(trialvec[i]))) {
   indexv <- is.element(ecf.df$Codon, unlist(trialvec[i]))
   name <- paste("Trial", i, sep = "_")
   currentT <- unlist(trialvec[i])
    for (f in 1:length(indexv)) {
      c[i] <- sum(is.element(currentT, 
                             aacodons$Amino_Acid[indexv][f]), 
                             na.rm = TRUE)
      TrialData[[i]] <- unlist(c)
    }
  }
  TrialData
}
```

When I try to run the function, emperical.Codon.frequency I get an error that reads:

> ERROR in TrialData[[i]] <- unlist(c): attempt to select less than one
>   element in intergerOneIndex.

```
dput(Trial1)

list(structure(c(5L, 7L, 7L, 17L, 14L, 3L), .Label = c("ala", 
"arg", "asn", "asp", "cys", "gln", "glu", "gly", "his", "ile", 
"leu", "lys", "met", "phe", "pro", "ser", "stop", "thr", "trp", 
"tyr", "val"), class = "factor"), structure(c(5L, 15L, 10L, 12L, 
5L, 2L), .Label = c("ala", "arg", "asn", "asp", "cys", "gln", 
"glu", "gly", "his", "ile", "leu", "lys", "met", "phe", "pro", 
"ser", "stop", "thr", "trp", "tyr", "val"), class = "factor"), 
    structure(c(4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 9L), .Label = c("ala", "arg", 
    "asn", "asp", "cys", "gln", "glu", "gly", "his", "ile", "leu", 
    "lys", "met", "phe", "pro", "ser", "stop", "thr", "trp", 
    "tyr", "val"), class = "factor"), structure(c(18L, 15L, 12L, 
    18L, 12L, 14L), .Label = c("ala", "arg", "asn", "asp", "cys", 
    "gln", "glu", "gly", "his", "ile", "leu", "lys", "met", "phe", 
    "pro", "ser", "stop", "thr", "trp", "tyr", "val"), class = "factor"), 
    structure(c(1L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 17L, 19L), .Label = c("ala", 
    "arg", "asn", "asp", "cys", "gln", "glu", "gly", "his", "ile", 
    "leu", "lys", "met", "phe", "pro", "ser", "stop", "thr", 
    "trp", "tyr", "val"), class = "factor"), structure(c(1L, 
    19L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("ala", "arg", "asn", "asp", 
    "cys", "gln", "glu", "gly", "his", "ile", "leu", "lys", "met", 
    "phe", "pro", "ser", "stop", "thr", "trp", "tyr", "val"), class = "factor"), 
    structure(c(14L, 14L, 19L, 3L, 12L, 14L), .Label = c("ala", 
    "arg", "asn", "asp", "cys", "gln", "glu", "gly", "his", "ile", 
    "leu", "lys", "met", "phe", "pro", "ser", "stop", "thr", 
    "trp", "tyr", "val"), class = "factor"), structure(c(13L, 
    5L, 9L, 21L, 16L, 13L), .Label = c("ala", "arg", "asn", "asp", 
    "cys", "gln", "glu", "gly", "his", "ile", "leu", "lys", "met", 
    "phe", "pro", "ser", "stop", "thr", "trp", "tyr", "val"), class = "factor"), 
    structure(c(2L, 21L, 8L, 16L, 3L, 17L), .Label = c("ala", 
    "arg", "asn", "asp", "cys", "gln", "glu", "gly", "his", "ile", 
    "leu", "lys", "met", "phe", "pro", "ser", "stop", "thr", 
    "trp", "tyr", "val"), class = "factor"), structure(c(10L, 
    11L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 17L), .Label = c("ala", "arg", "asn", 
    "asp", "cys", "gln", "glu", "gly", "his", "ile", "leu", "lys", 
    "met", "phe", "pro", "ser", "stop", "thr", "trp", "tyr", 
    "val"), class = "factor"))
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? Passing *Trial1* as input? Can you post its `dput()` so we can reproduce. Also where is *c* in `c[1]` initialized?

Comment: Yes I am passing Trial1 as input. what is dput()?

Comment: @Parfait it has been added.